# sub_items generate new columns in JSON to CSV converter with python

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert a JSON string to a CSV file which I can work on further in excel. For that, I am using the following script: https://github.com/vinay20045/json-to-csv

I was on that for a few hours yesterday but could not get it working :(
I reduced my json string to the minimum for the sake of explaining what I mean.
https://pastebin.com/Vjt799Bb

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "pages": 2270,
  "limit": 10,
  "total": 22693,
  "items": [
    {
      "address": {
        "city": "cityname first dataset",
        "company_name": "companyname first dataset"
      },
      "amount": 998,
      "items": [
        {
          "description": "first part of first dataset",
          "number": "part number of first part of first dataset"
        }
      ],
      "number": "number of first dataset",
      "service_date": {
        "type": "DEFAULT",
        "date": "2015-11-18"
      },
      "vat_option": null
    },
    {
      "address": {
        "city": "cityname second dataset",
        "company_name": "companyname second dataset"
      },
      "amount": 998,
      "items": [
        {
          "description": "first part of second dataset",
          "number": "part number of first part of second dataset"
        },
        {
          "description": "second part of second dataset",
          "number": "part number of second part of second dataset"
        }
      ],
      "number": "number of second dataset",
      "service_date": {
        "type": "DEFAULT",
        "date": "2015-11-18"
      },
      "vat_option": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I would really appreciate if you could take a look at it.

The script now delivers the following result:
.dropbox.com/s/165zbfl8wn52syf/scriptresult.jpg?dl=0
(please add www in front to have a link)

What the script now needs to do is following (F3, G4 and so on are cell definitions from the above screenshot):
- copy F3 and G3 to D4 and E4
- remove columns F and G
- copy A3:C3 to A4:C4
- copy F3:I3 to F4:I4

Target CSV will then look like:
.dropbox.com/s/l1wj3ntrlomwmaq/target.jpg?dl=0
(please add www in front to have a link)

So all in all, the „items_items_0“ „items_items_1“ is a problem because when the JSON data has sub_items, they will get new columns in the header with the current script. But I’d like to have them in new rows instead.

Do you see any chance how I can reach that? The logic is quite clear to me, but I am an absolute newbie in python - maybe that’s the problem :(

Thank you for your great support!

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: If you need help with a script that someone else wrote then you need to ask _them_ about it. Stack Overflow is here to help you with problems you have with code you wrote yourself.

Comment: Sure - you are right! Of course, he provided the script and now I need to take that and customize it to my needs. So in that way - I am going to produce own code which will extend that script.
Is it such da problem to ask about that?

Comment: You can certainly ask about code you're writing, but I see no code in your question. OTOH, to fully help you, people will need to study vinay's code as well as your code, and you may not find many people willing to do that for free.

Comment: Ideally, an SO question asks about a single specific problem you're having with the code you're writing, and it's illustrated by a [mcve] that focuses on that problem. Also, it's self-contained so all relevant information is present in the question itself. Links to other sites may be used to provide supporting information, but the question needs to be understandable and answerable just using the info on the question page itself.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree: You're asking about the usage of a specific package without providing the actual code.

I went ahead, made some assumptions, and created a snippet which could help you solve your issue. Instead of using the script you linked, I use a combination of manually creating a dictionary and then using Pandas to print, potential modification, and eventual export. *Note: This does not solve your problem (since I'm not really getting it to the fullest extend) – it rather hopes to give you a good start with some of the tools and techniques.*

See `.ipynb` file in this Gist, https://gist.github.com/AndiH/4d4ef85e2dec395a0ae5343c648565eb, the gist of it I'll paste below:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open("input.json") as f:
    rawjson = json.load(f)

data = []
for element in rawjson["items"]:
    data.append({
        "item_address_city": element["address"]["city"],
        "item_address_company_name": element["address"]["company_name"],
        "items_amount": element["amount"]
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()

df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: Since you're new to Python: The `.ipynb` file is a Jupyter Notebook file, which is great for interactive Python development – and works together well with Pandas. Jupyter Notebook can be installed with `pip`: http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html